# In Tizen, how can you disable the native virtual keyboard?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, tizen

I'm building an App for Tizen and I want to use my own jQuery keyboard instead of the Tizen's virtual IME Keyboard. The question is: How can I disable the Tizen's virtual keyboard in the whole app?

Any help on this?

Comment: Have you found answer to your question ? I am having same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll need some div + JS magic to make this happen.

Comment: You might want to include more info from https://what.thedailywtf.com/t/press-arrow-up-arrow-up-arrow-down-arrow-down-arrow-left-arrow-right-arrow-left-arrow-right-b-a-fa-windows-secret-to-post-status-thread/1673/28990

Answer (score -2):

Tizen wearables support the following .
To create the Web IME project, launch the Tizen IDE and go to File > New > Tizen Wearable Web Project > Template > IME Application > Web IME.
Enter the project name and click Finish.
Create a Web IME project
Modify the source code in, for example, the index.html and style.css files, as needed.

It works only on wearables as mentioned by the guide, but could be opened in future.